# After installing a theme in wordpress what plugins should i install in wordpress for better performance, speed , security and Also SEO?

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, elementor

this is my first post and i'm newbee, but have some information and Experience about wordpress and Elementor,
After installing a theme in wordpress what plugins should i install in wordpress for better performance, speed , security and Also SEO of website ?
please help me about this issue.thanks.

I'm just starting to build a online Drugstore website.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is related to coding problems, then your question seems to be off-topic here. Maybe this: [The Best WordPress Plugins for 2023](https://wpmarmite.com/en/best-wordpress-plugins/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For SEO > Yoast SEO : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

For Security > Wordfence Security: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

For Speed and Performance > WP Super Cache: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/

You can browse popular plugins, here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/browse/popular/